# Can someone help me finish the solution to this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the general solution of $(x-4y-3)dx-(x-6y-5)dy=0.$

The rest of my solution:

$x-4y=3$

$x-6y=5$

The point of intersection is $(-1, -1)$.

Let

$x=u-1$; $dx=du$

$y=v-1$; $dy=dv$

$(u-4v)du-(u-6v)dv=0$

Let $u=vz; du=vdz+zdv$

$(vz-4v)(vdz+zdv)-(vz-6v)dv=0$

$(z-4)(vdz+zdv)-(z-6)dv=0$

$(z^2-5z+6)dv-v(z-4)dz=0$

$\frac{dv}{v}-\frac{z-4}{(z^2-5z+6)}dz=0$

$\int\frac{dv}{v}-\int \frac{z-4}{(z^2-5z+6)}dz=0$

$\int\frac{dv}{v}-2\int \frac{dz}{(z-2)}+\int\frac{dz}{z-3}=0$

$\ln \lvert v\rvert -2\ln \lvert z-2\rvert +\ln \lvert z-3 \rvert + \ln \lvert c \rvert=0$

$\ln\lvert cv(z-3) \rvert =2\ln \lvert z-2 \rvert$

$\ln \lvert (z-2)^2 \rvert = \ln\lvert cv(z-3) \rvert $

I do not know how the final answer became $(x-2y-1)^2=c(x-3y-2).$

Answer (score 1):

You find :
$$\ln((z-2)^2)=\ln(cv(z-3))$$
$$(z-2)^2=cv(z-3)$$
$z=\frac{u}{v}$
$$(\frac{u}{v}-2)^2=cv(\frac{u}{v}-3)$$
$$(u-2v)^2=cv^2(u-3v)$$
$u=x+1$ and $v=y+1$
$$((x+1)-2(y+1))^2=c(y+1)^2((x+1)-3(y+1))$$
$$(x-2y-1)^2=c(y+1)^2(x-3y-2)$$